# Get/Display all results from Array that matches condition

Tags: power-automate

New to power automate. I've created a flow that gets specific rows from an html_to_text output. That one works fine, but the requirement is that I also need to display rows that contain "FAIL"

What I did was to create an array and then a condition where "Current item contains FAIL". If "yes", then it will display the current item + the initial output for the other string.

I have 240 rows of html_to_text data.

The apply_to_each and its condition works, but I don't know how to display ALL of the outputs that had 'FAIL' string in them in one Compose.

[image: If expression result is false]

[image: if expression result is true]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter and the data is an array I would suggest to use the Filter Array action.

Try something like below

[image]

Comment: Yes, I've actually done this that's why I was able to get the items with which was included in my screenshot :) I've found the solution to display it: https://blog.thenetw.org/2022/06/27/compose-in-apply-to-each/

Answer (score 0):

Found this: https://blog.thenetw.org/2022/06/27/compose-in-apply-to-each/ and did the steps to combine all outputs.